# Node.js get's stuck on a while loop, and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, while-loop

So, I've been recently working on an interpreter for a very small, custom programming language for performing FileSystem operations. Currently, I am working on some sort of lexer, and am having an issue, where it gets stuck on a while loop, and after sometime obviously results in a heap out of memory error. Here's the code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const tt_comma = 'comma'
const tt_string = 'string'
const tt_keywords = ['delete', 'write', 'append', 'copy', 'rename', 'move']

class Token {
    constructor(type, value) {
        this.type = type
        if (value) {
            this.value = value
        }
    }


}

class Lexer {

    constructor(src) {
        this.pos = -1
        this.currentCharacter = ''
        this.src = src
        this.advance(1)
        console.log(this.tokenize())
    }

    advance(amount) {
        this.pos += amount
        console.log(`Advanced ${amount} characters`)
        this.currentCharacter = this.src[this.pos]
        console.log(`Current character: '${this.pos}:${this.currentCharacter}'`)
    }

    tokenize() {
        let tokens = []
        while (this.pos < this.src.length) {
            if (this.currentCharacter === ' ' || this.currentCharacter === '\t') {
                this.advance(1)
            }
            if (this.currentCharacter === '"') {
                let str = '';
                while (this.currentCharacter !== '"') {
                    this.advance()
                    str += this.currentCharacter
                }
                tokens.push(new Token(tt_string, str))
            }
            else {
                for (let i = 0; i < tt_keywords.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof this.src.indexOf(tt_keywords[i], this.src.length) == 'number') {
                        tokens.push(new Token(tt_keywords[i]))
                        this.advance(tt_keywords[i].length)
                        break
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Error('Lazy error')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tokens
    }

}

let lexer = new Lexer(fs.readFileSync('main.fss',"ascii"))
```

Comment: `while (this.currentCharacter !== '"') {                    this.advance()`
Here you dont move position. Undefined is converted to zero when you use it in math operations

Comment: @Darth thanks a lot. Can't believe I made this stupid of a mistake...

Comment: That looks unreachable. I might be missing something though.